# How to iterate over list of list ( nested list ) in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have list of list such as :

```
data = [ ['a', 'b' ], ['a1', 'b1'], ['c1', 'd1' ] ]
```

I want to iterate over and access both elements of each nested list same time

something like:

```
for elements in ??
do
    python3 main.py --argument1 elements[0] --arguments2 elements[1]
done
```

How to access each element in the nested list?

I have tried this:

```
a1=( a a1 c1 )
a2=( b b1 d1 )

declare -i i=0

while [ "${a1[i]}" -a "${a2[i]}" ]; do

    printf " %s  %s\n" "${a1[i]}" "${a2[i]}"
    ((i++))

done

exit 0
```

Comment: The script you tried is how you'd do it (i.e. using two or more arrays and using the same iterator with them) - bash does not support nested or multi-dimensional arrays.   If you need that, use a language which does support them.  perl for example.  or python :-).  and both perl and python have the ability, like shell does, to execute external programs, so can be used to write wrapper scripts.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There are no lists of lists in bash so saying `I have list of list` as a starting premise is just wrong - if you're in bash then you don't have that and if you're not in bash then why are you trying to use bash for this? Please [edit] your question to explain what you're actually trying to do (as opposed to how you're trying to do it).

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no such thing as a list of lists in `bash`, we will assume that you want to iterate over two lists pairwise in a loop, which your code also seems to indicate. Furthermore, we will assume that the two lists always contain the same number of elements and that the lists are not sparse.

You may write your loop to iterate with indexes or with the elements themselves.

The following is an example of how to loop over the indexes of one of the arrays and use that to access the elements in both arrays.

```bsh
a1=( a a1 c1 )
a2=( b b1 d1 )

for i in "${!a1[@]}"; do
        printf 'Pair: (%s,%s)\n' "${a1[i]}" "${a2[i]}"
done
```

The expression `"${!a1[@]}"` will expand to a list containing the indexes of the array `a1`.

You may also use the elements of the arrays directly in a loop.

```bsh
a1=( a a1 c1 )
a2=( b b1 d1 )

set -- "${a1[@]}"

for b in "${a2[@]}"; do
        a=$1; shift
        printf 'Pair: (%s,%s)\n' "$a" "$b"
done
```

Here, we set the list of positional parameters to the elements from the `a1` array using `set` and then loop over the elements of the other array.  The value `$b` is an element from `a2` in the loop, and `$1` is the first positional parameter (the next element from `a1`).  This `$1` value is assigned to `a` and then shifted off the positional parameters list.

Both pieces of code above would generate the same output.

```
Pair: (a,b)
Pair: (a1,b1)
Pair: (c1,d1)
```

---

The main issue with the code you show is that you don't know whether you've come to the end of the arrays when you encounter an empty element.  Empty elements are and must be allowed in an array.  The syntax with `-a` inside of `[ ... ]` is better avoided and replaced with `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` due to ambiguities that could occur, and you should also test with `-n` for non-empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

As you change data and arrnum, you can achieve your purpose with the multi-dimensional arrays:

```
data=( a b a1 b1 c1 d1 )
arrnum=2
len=${#data[@]}

declare -i i=0

while [ "$len" -gt "$((i*arrnum))" ]; do

    for (( j=0; j<$arrnum-1; j++ )); do
    printf " %s  " "${data[i*arrnum+j]}"
    done
        printf " %s\n" "${data[i*arrnum+j]}"
    
    ((i++))

done

exit 0
```

result :

[image: 1]